# DrawerLayout home button not working after returning to activity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity, drawerlayout

So, I've got an extension of Fragment activity called `SlidingFragmentActivity` which I use as a base for activities that I want to show my DrawerLayout on. Everything works fine, until you press the back button and try to open the drawer using the Home button. Nothing happens. Swiping from the bezel still works though. I've also tried `DrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);` to no avail.

Starting the activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` does the same.

All the code is copied from [this example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) so I don't see why it shouldn't work?

Here's the complete `SlidingFragmentActivity`:

```
public class SlidingFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public static ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // Fragment manager
    public FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sliding_menu);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close 
            );

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...
        return true;
    }

    public static void openDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
}
```

I'm no by no means an expert on activity lifecycles but I'm guessing it's something to do with the instanceState?

Anybody else run into this problem/know how to fix it?

Comment: Solved, I'd set mDrawerLayout and mDrawerToggle to be static for some reason.